# ajaxctroltoolkik.ModalPopupextender. Stops working after 10 calls to Show()

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I have problems with the ModalPopupExtender. 
I set the targetcontrolid to a hidden field and calls the show method from code behind. Every thing works fine until the 10th time i call the show method. Then it suddenly stops working. The "dialog" is no where to be seen. The controls on the page no longer gets disabled. The code behind get called when i click the button that is calling the show method but calls to the show method has no effect.

I use Visual Studio 2010

Here is my aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MessageBoxTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="SeceOfC2.TEST.MessageBoxTest" %>
<%@ Register tagName="MessageBox" tagPrefix="uc" src="~/Dialogs/MessageBox.ascx" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="TestButton" Text="Test" OnClick="TestButton_OnClick" />





            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="_Hint"/> <%--Brukt til å vite hvorfor denne dialogen ble kalt.--%>
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="_Parameters"/> <%--Her lagres parameterdata som en Json string.--%>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="_dummy"/>
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="MessageBoxPanel">
                <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="MessageBoxBorderPanel" BorderColor="LightGray">
                    <div class="dialogheader">
                        <div style="text-align: center; float: left">
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbHeader"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div style="float:right">
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Icons/Small/navigate_cross.png"  />
                        </div>
                        <div style="clear:both"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dialogbody" style="min-height: 50px">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbBody"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dialogbody" style="text-align: center">
                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="OKButton" Text="OK" OnClick="OnOkClicked"/>
                    </div>
                </asp:Panel>
            </asp:Panel>
            <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="MessageBoxPopupExtender" TargetControlID="_dummy" PopupControlID="MessageBoxPanel" RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowResizeAndScroll" PopupDragHandleControlID="MessageBoxBorderPanel" DropShadow="True" />



        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>


</asp:Content>
```

The masterpage containing the script manager:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SeceOfC2.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <script language="JavaScript1.2" src="/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript" defer="defer"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onresize = function(event) {
            var height = $(window).height();
            var width = $(window).width();

            $.ajax({
                url: "/HttpHandlers/getwindowsize.ashx",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    Height: height,
                    Width: width,
                    selectedValue: selectedValue
                },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                    // do stuff
                }

            });
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>
                    SenseOfC Drill execution prototype
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="loginDisplay">
                <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                        [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/"/> ]
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </div>
            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Content/Users/DrillView.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Content/Administrators/TreatmentView.aspx" 
                            Text="Admin" Value="Admin"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using SeceOfC2.Dialogs;
using SeceOfC2.Tools;

namespace SeceOfC2.TEST
{
    public partial class MessageBoxTest : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void TestButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Show("TEST", "TEST");
        }



        public void Show(string caption, string message, string hint = "", MessageBox.Buttons buttons = MessageBox.Buttons.Ok)
        {
            _Hint.Value = hint;
            _Parameters.Value = JsonHelper.Serialize("");
            lbHeader.Text = caption;
            lbBody.Text = message;
            MessageBoxPopupExtender.Show();
        }


        protected void OnOkClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }
    }
}
```

If i set the TargetControlID to a visible control. The ModalPopupExtender still works, but no code behid is called, obviously, preventing me from puting any data in to the fields in the dialog.

**Update:**
I have testet in a standard aspx page (no masterpage):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MessageBoxTestNoMaster.aspx.cs" Inherits="SeceOfC2.TEST.MessageBoxTestNoMaster" %>
<%@ Register tagName="MessageBox" tagPrefix="uc" src="~/Dialogs/MessageBox.ascx" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="TEST" Text="Test" OnClick="TEST_OnClick"/>

            <uc:MessageBox runat="server" ID="MessageBox" />            
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The dialog has been moved to a usercontrol:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MessageBox.ascx.cs" Inherits="SeceOfC2.Dialogs.MessageBox" %>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="_Hint"/> <%--Brukt til å vite hvorfor denne dialogen ble kalt.--%>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="_Parameters"/> <%--Her lagres parameterdata som en Json string.--%>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="dummy"/>
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="MessageBoxPanel">
    <%--<ajaxToolkit:DropShadowExtender ID="DropShadowExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="MessageBoxBorderPanel" Opacity="0.1" Radius="10"/>--%>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="MessageBoxBorderPanel" BorderColor="LightGray">
        <div class="dialogheader">
            <div style="text-align: center; float: left">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbHeader"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div style="float:right">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Icons/Small/navigate_cross.png" OnClick="OnCloseClicked" />
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="dialogbody" style="min-height: 50px">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbBody"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div class="dialogbody" style="text-align: center">
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="OKButton" Text="OK" OnClick="OnOkClicked"/>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="CancelButton" Text="Avbryt" OnClick="OnCancelClicked"/>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="YesButton" Text="Ja" OnClick="OnYesClicked"/>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="NoButton" Text="Nei" OnClick="OnNoClicked"/>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="MessageBoxPopupExtender" TargetControlID="dummy" PopupControlID="MessageBoxPanel" RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowResizeAndScroll" PopupDragHandleControlID="MessageBoxBorderPanel" DropShadow="True" />
```

At this point there is no reference to the css classes used so the dialog looks a bit naked, but it works!! I can show and hide the dialog as many times as I want.

**Update 2:**
Link to the css-file is no problem. Now the dialog looks as it should.

**Upate 3:** 
Tried to move the reference to scriptmanager from masterpage to page. Same result. Does not work.

**Update 4:**
Removed the refrecence to css file. The message box now works.

**Update 5:**
I'm not quit there yet but a bit longer than just a few minutes ago.

The problem seems to be connected to the standard asp. web application you get out of the box from Visual Studio 2010 and the CSS file you get located in the Styles catalog. I will try to fiddle a bit with it and maybe I can figure out what is chrasning with the ModalPopupExtender.

[After deactivating some more of the classes in the css files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyI0u.png)

The message box is suddenly placed behind the other stuff in the form and its no longer modal. I can click on any part of the form I want and events geting fired.

**Update 6:**
I have reproduced the error without masterpage and only a singel styling element:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MessageBoxTestNoMaster.aspx.cs" Inherits="SeceOfC2.TEST.MessageBoxTestNoMaster" %>
<%@ Register tagName="MessageBox" tagPrefix="uc" src="~/Dialogs/MessageBox.ascx" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
            <style type="text/css">
    .page
    {
        width: 960px;
        background-color: #fff;
        margin: 20px 0px;
        border: 1px solid #496077;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">


    <div class="page">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="TEST" Text="Test" OnClick="TEST_OnClick"/>

            <uc:MessageBox runat="server" ID="MessageBox" />            
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[This is what it looks like without master page and only one style element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9NcF.png)

The dialog is visible but hiding behind the div with class "page". Hapens after 10 calls to show method. The modal functionality is no longer active and I can click both the ok button in the dialog and the button in the form that is calling the show method.

Comment: So it works without master page, but with master page you can call it exactly 10 times? Or 10 times in average?

Comment: 10 times. But I have also discovered that the problem occurs earlier if i involve listview located inside the same updatepanel as the messagebox user control, and eventhandling from list items. With this test, how ever,  its exactly 10 times each time.

Comment: I think the reason why it works without master page, but with the same css is that some part of the css file is not used in the master page less test.

Comment: Found the son of a b****ch: Its the styling of the page element: .page
{
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid #496077;
}

Comment: Not sure what is going on here, but Im geting closer.

Comment: Fund a workaround I hope to get rid of as soon as posible: Catch the DialogResult event in the messagebox and force a full postback: 

protected void MessageBox_OnDialogResult(object sender, MessageBoxEventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
        }

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem with the AjaxControlToolkit 15.4.1 ModalPopupExtender, and what solved it for me was (1) making sure all buttons were in a PostBackTrigger tag, i.e.:

```
</ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnDownload" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

... and then also (2) removing the "CancelButtonID" property if it existed and using an actual button click or command event to hide the extender.

I wish I could say why this worked, but I don't know enough about the control toolkit to say... hope that helps!